# Make JSON files to have TextMate2 icon

Tags: macos, icon, file

I have all the *JSON* files on my system set to open with TextMate 2.
When I get Info on one of these *.js* files, I see the TextMate 2 icon on the corner. But, how do I make for the TextMate icon to appear while in Finder's icon mode too?

I'm using Mountain Lion, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The tm2 icon in the corner is "The Icon From Textmate"

Comment: What do they currently show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select any .js file and press "Command+i".
Go to "Open with".
Select TextMate 2 from the drop down and click "Change all".

Now you can see the TM icons in finder.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to settings -> icons settings -> set files icons.

Comment: Which application are you referring to here?

Comment: system preferences or finder?